# The method isNullOrEmpty(String) is undefined for the type StringUtils

Tags: java, methods, undefined, string-utils

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.apache.log4j.MDC;
import java.util.UUID;

import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerInterceptorAdapter;

/**
 * A webflow request interceptor injecting correlation id to the request context.
 */
public class TestController extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    private static final String CORRELATION_ID_HEADER_NAME = "X-Correlation-Id";
    private static final String CORRELATION_ID_LOG_VAR_NAME = "correlationId";

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response,
                             final Object handler) throws Exception {
        final String correlationId = getCorrelationIdFromHeader(request);
        MDC.put(CORRELATION_ID_LOG_VAR_NAME, correlationId);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void afterCompletion(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response,
                             final Object handler, final Exception ex) throws Exception {
        MDC.remove(CORRELATION_ID_LOG_VAR_NAME);
    }

    private String getCorrelationIdFromHeader(final HttpServletRequest request) {
        String correlationId = request.getHeader(CORRELATION_ID_HEADER_NAME);
        ***if (StringUtils.isNullOrEmpty(correlationId)) {***
            correlationId = generateUniqueCorrelationId();
        }
        return correlationId;
    }

    private String generateUniqueCorrelationId() {
        return UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    }
}
```

i tried to run this program but the error comes can u help me? i am learning correlation ID on logging but cant find the right and good source then i found site which show this code can someone help:)

P.S the error is The method isNullOrEmpty(String) is undefined for the type StringUtils.. on the line where i give *** on the code above

Comment: What is the exact error ? can you post the error please

Comment: You can use isEmpty method. It internally checks for null.

Comment: @DEBENDRADHINDA the error is in the title The method isNullOrEmpty(String) is undefined for the type StringUtils

Comment: @NitishBhardwaj when i change to isEmpty method.. it said something like this The method isEmpty(String) is undefined for the type StringUtils

Comment: @stephen090 Which version of Spring you are using....there is no isNullOrEmpty() method.. https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/StringUtils.html#method.summary

Comment: @DEBENDRADHINDA hmm.. my version is 3.1.2.. i got this from article on 2015.. any recommendation to fix this problem?

Comment: Write your own isNullOrEmpty() method? (it's a single line of code: shouldn't be too hard)

Comment: Or consider using `org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.isEmpty(s)`, i.e. whereever you copied the code from probably used a different StringUtils

Answer (score 0):

You are using `org.springframework.util.StringUtils` which has a method `isEmpty(value)`. However, you probably want [Apache's Commons Lang](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) which has a much more complete StringUtils.